# Mysql errors while trying to 'insert into select on duplicate key'

Tags: mysql

What I want to do is a classic insert or update case but with a 'select' instead of 'values'. I don't think the exact database structure matters in this case, suppose all fields I use in the example are integers. I try to run 2 cases but they both yield errors:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c) 
    SELECT x, SUM(y), COUNT(z)
    FROM table2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b = b + x;
```

this yields

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'x' in 'field list'

The second case:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c) 
    SELECT x, SUM(y), COUNT(z)
    FROM table2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b = b + count(z);
```

this yields

> Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

In both cases if I remove the duplicate key statement everything works. Also, in both cases the value I want to use in updating b from table 1 is the value from the row in the 'select' where duplicate key occurred. I'm guessing it has to do with the aggregate functions used but otherwise I'm at a loss. Inserting `GROUP BY` statements did not help in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `VALUES()` function:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c) 
    SELECT x, SUM(y), COUNT(z)
    FROM table2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b = b + VALUES(a);
```

The second case would use `VALUES(c)` rather than `VALUES(a)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However if I would want to continue referencing the values down the stack, for example:

INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c) 
    SELECT x, SUM(y), COUNT(z)
    FROM table2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b = b + (SELECT COUNT(x) FROM table2 WHERE -- some condition involving VALUES(a);

it doesn't seem to hold. Any idea why?

Comment: @Vee6 . . . Gosh, I've never tried subqueries in the `on duplicate key` expression.  You can probably incorporate that into the main `select` somehow.